# using moment how do we change or set date and keep unix time format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Can we use moment to change or set the date and maintain the unix time format.

current time format is 1629442800 which in human eyes August 20, 2021 3:00:00 AM. 
I would like to change just the date but keep the time the same

```
current time format is 1629442800 which in human eyes August 20, 2021 3:00:00 AM
```

```
desired time 1630047600 which in human eyes  August 27, 2021 3:00:00 AM
```

```
//using javascript  not sure how to use this
const currentTime = 1629442800

moment(currentTime).set('year', 2013);
moment(currentTime).set('month', 3);  // April
moment(currentTime).set('date', 1);

console.log(currentTime)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create multiple distinct date objects with each call of `moment(currentTime)`, and `currentTime` will only be used to initialize that data. `currentTime` won't be affected by any of the `.set` calls.

So this part of the code is completely useless:

```
moment(currentTime).set('year', 2013);
moment(currentTime).set('month', 3);  // April
moment(currentTime).set('date', 1);
```

You just create the moment date objects, calling `.set` on them and then you discard the result.

It has to be:

```js
const currentTime = 1629442800

// create a moment time object
const timeObject = moment.unix(currentTime)

// do changes on that object
timeObject.set('year', 2013);
timeObject.set('month', 3);  // April
timeObject.set('date', 1);

// get the unix timestamp form that moment object
console.log(timeObject.unix())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works but for some reason it is changing the time object as well. For example current time 1629442800 = August 20, 2021 3:00:00 AM when I run the code it go to April 1, 2013 3:37:22 PM. NOTE the date is correct but time is not the same it should April 1, 2013 3:00:00 AM

Comment: @Jerry Seigle  I have not seen that `currentTime` is in seconds and not milliseconds (as it is normally done in js). Updated the answer.